# Revolution slider и Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

В моем приложении я использую Revolution slider. Цель - на странице показать все продукты в слайдере, тоесть каждый отдельный продукт - это отдельный слайд. В данный момент, я вижу первый продукт в слайдере, но когда я нажимаю навигационную стрелку, ничего не происходит, и в консоли браузера я вижу: `No route matches [GET] "/undefined"`. Как мне задать правильное поведение для навигационных стрелок, что бы они не ссылались на несуществующий роут? Спасибо заранее.

**Добавлено:**

Получилось сделать переключение слайдов, но ошибка в консоли осталась.

Comment: Из того, что написано, есть подозрение что слайдер не правильно инициализируется. Нужен js-код его подключения / использования.

Comment: Я закинул все нужные js файлы в `vendor/assets/javascripts` и подключил их в манифесте `application.js`. То же самое и с `css`.